# How to pass form value from one component to a list in another component using angular services?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have been trying to develop a todo list project. I have four components : **Daily, Item-List, Item and Add-task dailog** [image]

The daily component holds a form and a list that displays the values from form. What I am looking to do next is to have a form in a dialog modal(new separate component) and add its value to the list in the daily component

Below are the codes:

**Daily.service.ts**

This service code is used to get the value from the form and add it to the list.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DailyTask } from './models';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DailyService {

private _dailies$ = new BehaviorSubject<DailyTask[]>([]); 
public getDailies(): DailyTask[] {
return this._dailies$.getValue();
}

public setDailies(data: DailyTask[]): void {
 this._dailies$.next(data);
}

public getDailiesObservable(): Observable<DailyTask[]> {
return this._dailies$.asObservable();
}

public createTask(newTask: string): void{

console.log( "check");

  const dailyTask: DailyTask = { task: newTask, type: 'DAILY' };
  this.setDailies([dailyTask, ...this.getDailies()])
 }
}
```

**Daily.component.Ts**

```
export class DailyComponent implements OnInit {
  public dailyList$: Observable<DailyTask[]> | null = null;

  constructor(private _dailyService: DailyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dailyList$ = this._dailyService.getDailiesObservable();
  }

  public addDaily(name: string) {
     this._dailyService.createTask(name);
  }
 }
```

**Daily.component.html**

```
 <mat-card>
   <h1>Daily</h1>
    <app-item-list
      [type]="'DAILY'"
      [initialData$]="dailyList$"
      [onAddItem]="addDaily.bind(this)"
    ></app-item-list>
 </mat-card>
```

**Item-List.component.html**

```
<div>
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
 <input
  matInput
  placeholder="Add a Task"
  (keyup.enter)="addTask()"
  autocomplete="off"
  [formControl]="nameControl"/>
 </mat-form-field>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="filteredData$ | async as data">

<app-item
  [value]="value"
  *ngFor="let value of data; index as index"
  (inputDataChange)="removeTask(data, index)"
>
</app-item>
</ng-container>
```

**Item-list.component.ts**

```
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {
   
   nameControl = new FormControl('');
   @Input() public type: ItemType | null = null;
   @Input() public onAddItem: Function | null = null;
   
   constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {}
   ngOnInit(): void {}

   addTask() {
     if (this.onAddItem) {
        this.onAddItem(this.nameControl.value);
        this.nameControl.reset();
   }
 }
```

**item.component.html**

```
<div class="displayTask">
  <div class="displayvalue" [ngClass]="{ 'line-through': value.task }">
     {{ value.task | uppercase }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**item.component.ts**

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
   value: any;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
 }
```

The above set of codes works perfect, below the code for new component **task-dailog**

**task-dailog.html**

```
<div mat-dialog-title class="dailogHeader">
   <h1 >Create Daily</h1>
</div>

<div mat-dialog-content>
    <div class="dialogContent">
      <p>Task</p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Add a new Task"
        autocomplete="off"
        (keyup.enter)="addDailogTask()"
        [formControl]="nameControl"
    />
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

**task-dailog.component.ts**

```
export class TaskDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  nameControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TaskDialogComponent>,
    private _dailyService: DailyService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  addDailogTask(){
    const value$ =   this.nameControl.value;
    this.nameControl.reset();
    console.log(value$);
  }
 }
```

Here in the task-dialog.component.ts, I have the function to get the value from the form, but I am stuck here and dont know how to proceed. I would like to learn how to send this form value from **TaskDialogComponent** to the list inside **DailyComponent**.

Here is also the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pdhugz?file=src/app/daily/daily.component.html) for the project.

Can someone help me with this . I am relatively new to angular and would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast your form value type first, By default `form.value` can be return as `any` that isn't match `createTask` function that require only `string`

**Solution**

```
addDailogTask() {
  const value$ = this.nameControl.value as string;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-pdhugz-sbinrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-task-btn%2Fadd-task-btn.component.ts

1. There were some issues with `task-dialog.component.html`. Basically, you want to 2-way bind the Task input field. You have to specify `[mat-dialog-close]="task"` to explicitly send the data from the dialog to the `dialogRef` in the `AddTaskBtnComponent`
2. Once the dialog is wired properly.. you can get the value from the dialog in the `afterClosed().subscribe` method.

   **add-task-btn.component.ts**:

   ```
   @Component({
    selector: 'app-add-task-btn',
    templateUrl: './add-task-btn.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add-task-btn.component.scss'],
   })
   export class AddTaskBtnComponent implements OnInit {


     ...

    openDialog(): void {

      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TaskDialogComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      height: '500px',
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((task) => {
        if (task) {
          this.dailyService.createTask(task);
        } 
        console.log('The dialog was closed');
      });
     }
    }
   }
   ```
3. `MatDialogModule` was not imported in `TaskDialogModule`

---

I see some problems with your code and how it is structured.

**Tips:**

1. You want to structure your code in the same way as how your UI is structured. So it would be easier to work with.
   for example:

   ```
   src
     app
     L home
       L shared
         L components
            L item-list
                L components
                   L item 
       L components
          L profile-banner
          L searchbar
          L add-task-btn
          L daily
            L components
            L services
              L daily.service.ts
            L ... 
          L todo
          L habits 
       L services
       L models 
       L home.component.ts
       L home.component.scss
       L home.component.html
   ```
2. Not sure why you decided to put each component in a separate module. Which is unnecessary technically the login page could be in one module and everything else that is in the homecomponent could be in another module. That way you can lazyload the `HomeModule`.
3. When you have a deeply nested component. I would recommend to use a state management library (I use ngxs) its a lot easier to work with so you don't have to pass values through the `@input` decorator. Also it would make your code a lot more readable.